# Multiple spaces in GET causes err_Conection_Reset

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm using JavaScript to send a GET to a php file.

```
function getLessons(lesson){
    if(xmlHttpGetLessons.readyState==4 || xmlHttpGetLessons.readyState == 0){
        var lesson_title = encodeURIComponent(lesson);
        xmlHttpGetLessons.open("GET", 'InstListLessons.php?lesson=' + lesson_title,true);
        xmlHttpGetLessons.send(null);
        xmlHttpGetLessons.onreadystatechange = LessonGetServerResponse;
    } 
}
```

The PHP file receives the GET and processes the data:

```
if (isset($_GET['lesson'])){
    $lesson_tmp = urldecode($_GET['lesson']);
    $lesson_descrip = Filter_var($lesson_tmp, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
} else {
    $flag = false;
}
```

under most circumstances this works fine and the PHP returns the data in XML format with no issues. When the value of 'lesson' has one space it works fine. The GET is sent as

```
"InstListLessons.php?lesson=Sutures%20Stiching"
```

When there are two spaces the GET still seems to send correctly

```
"InstListLessons.php?lesson=Sutures%20and%20Stiching"
```

However the page fails to load with

```
GET http://192.168.1.18/InstListLessons.php?lesson=Sutures%20and%20Stiching net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
```

If I just remove the second "%20Stiching" it works, so I don't believe that there is an actual connection issue.  How can I send the string with two spaces?  would POST work better?

Comment: Is it wrong to use text with spaces this way, transform space to &nbsp; ;) this way you got space on html side and no space on a call

Comment: This shouldn't be an issue at all, and you shouldn't have to use `urldecode` at all either.

Comment: @Goikiu - adding &nbsp causes $lesson_tmp to get cut off after the first word.

Comment: @adeneo - you're right this shouldn't be a problem with is why i'm mystified?  I added urldecode as an attempt to get it working properly.

Comment: I have no clue what's going on here, there's no reason for the URL not to work regardless of what the querystring is, and it does in fact seem to work, but the connection is reset, which probably means an invalid packet was sent. The question then becomes, why is the `XMLHttpRequest.send()` function inside a function with a condition that checks the readystate, that seems pretty darn strange ?

Comment: @adeneo, obviously I'm somewhat new with AJAX, my understanding was to put it in the function because we didn't want to send the same request if it was still processing. States 0 and 4 would indicate that it is not currently processing.  Either way, i use the code quite often and it works fine, I don't believe that is the issue. The issue is most definitely related to the second "%20" in the GET variable.

Comment: Until I get a better solution:  In javascript I replaced all of the spaces with "~" before sending GET, in PHP i replaced all "~" with spaces and it seems to work.

Comment: Does it work if you GET InstListLessons.php?lesson=Sutures+and+Stiching instead?

Comment: Also, "Stitching" is misspelled, so if it is trying to load data with that name that is not misspelled, that would be a problem.

Comment: @Listhis adding the "+" does not work, the page returns the same error. Also the spaces are required in the query that will be sent to the SQL server. Misspelling doesn't matter at this point, the page would still load, it would just fail to find records and return a "No Records Found" string in the final XML file.